# C# ref/out parameters vs. laziness

Tags: c#, .net

I have a method which has several "out" parameters. They are out as the value should be set to them inside the function. But in some cases compiler is not clever enough and it doesn't see parameter value is set in any execution path. That's why I have to set default values to out parameters at the beginning of the method. But as this method is part of interface with several implementations this initialization code is duplicated. And I don't like it.

What options do you see to solve this problem? One option I see is to use ref instead of out. It isn't conceptually right as it doesn't guarantee parameter value will be set inside a method. But in fact it is the same (as I have default values setting at the beginning of the function, which means out in this case doesn't guarantee real values are set inside a method).

Any other options?

Comment: Can you show us an example of how/where the "compiler is not clever enough"?

Comment: Yeah, I've never seen the compiler unable to deduce out assignment.

Comment: `private void Foo(out int bar)
        {
            int[] blah = { 1 };

            foreach (var item in blah)
            {
                bar = 5;
            }
        }` - It will *always* be assigned, logically, but the compiler doesn't catch it.

Comment: @LukeH: Coincidentally, your question (that is, "when is the compiler not clever enough and how clever can it in theory be?") will be the subject of my blog on Thursday.

Comment: @Adam: I'm aware that it's relatively easy to craft code that can outwit the compiler's flow analysis; I was hoping that the OP might show us a specific example of where's it's failing *for them* so that we could suggest alternative patterns. @Eric: Looking forward to it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Personally, I try to avoid making a method that has "several" `ref` or `out` parameters.

As soon as you create a method that has more than a single `ref` or `out` parameter, personally, I feel it's time to consider refactoring to have it return a custom type (`class` or `struct` depending on the context) containing all of the data.  This has many advantages, especially since it allows that type to handle its own validation for correctness in the construction of the type.

This is especially true if you have "multiple implementations" - as this should dramatically reduce the likelihood of errors as well as eliminating most of the duplicated code (since it can go into the new type).

Answer (score 10):

Any method having several out parameters is a design smell to start with, to be honest. Do you really need these to be separate parameters, rather than one well-encapsulated return value? That would only be the case if the values were unrelated... in which case perhaps your method is doing too much in the first place.

Virtually the only place I regularly encounter `out` parameters in the framework is `TryParse` methods - and if `Tuple<T1, T2>` had been available when they were designed, I *suspect* that would have been used in the first place. Alternatively, a `ParseResult<T>` struct would be appropriate.